# Javascript Replace Onblur

Tags: javascript, input, replace, getelementbyid, onblur

I want to replace "ı,ğ,ş" with "i,g,s".
This is my code but i cant find my fault.
And i have to do it with oblur event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function replacer()
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
x.value=x.value.replace("ı","i");
x.value=x.value.replace("ş","s");
x.value=x.value.replace("ğ","g");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Name :<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="replacer()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just copied your code into jsfiddle and it works fine? http://jsfiddle.net/zxFHu/

Comment: And it works for me [at *this* JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HsdWt/). Though I'd suggest changing to: [`x.value=x.value.replace(/ğ/g,"g");`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HsdWt/1/) (for example) to replace *all* instances of that character. Perhaps I should've asked first, but: what makes you think you have a fault, and what browser(s)/platform(s) are you using/testing on?

Comment: look at the source code if that letters are not encoded

Comment: another shorthand can be x.value=x.value.replace("ı","i").replace("ş","s").replace("ğ","g");

Comment: Works for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/aSjbL/